# Handling multiple keypressess at the same time in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm making a simple top down 2D shooter, where you move with WASD and shoot in the direction you're looking at with space. I can move and shoot just fine, but I can't do them both at the same time. For example if I'm shooting and start moving, my character will stop shooting until I release and press space again, and if I then start moving in another direction I have to release and press space again.

Here's my main method:

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if (!init())
    {
        log("Failed to initialize!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        log("Initialized SDL and SDL subsystems. \nLoading assets:\n");

        if (!loadAssets())
        {
            printf("Failed to load assets!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            log("All assets loaded successfully.\n");

            bool running = true;
            SDL_Event e;
            std::vector<Shot> shots;

            LTimer shotTimer;
            float cooldown = 250.0f;
            float previousCooldown = 0.0f;

            Player player;

            log("Game running.\n");
            shotTimer.start();
            while (running)
            {
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
                {
                    if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                    {
                        log("SDL_QUIT event triggered.\n");
                        running = false;
                    }
                    else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                    {
                        switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
                        {
                            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                            {
                                running = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    player.handleEvent(e);

                    if (SDL_GetTicks() - previousCooldown > cooldown)
                    {
                        previousCooldown = SDL_GetTicks();

                        shots = shoot(e, player, shots);
                    }
                }

                player.move();
                for (int i = 0; i < shots.size(); i++)
                {
                    shots[i].move();
                }

                /*if (shotTimer.getTicks() >= cooldown)
                    shotTimer.restart();*/

                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
                SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

                background.render(0, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < shots.size(); i++)
                {
                    shots[i].render();
                }
                player.render();

                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
            }
        }
    }

    close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my shoot() function, which is probably what's causing this:

```
std::vector<Shot> shoot(SDL_Event& e, Player player, std::vector<Shot> shots)
{
    bool shoot = false;

    if (e.type = SDL_KEYDOWN  && e.key.repeat == 1)
    {
        switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_SPACE:
            {
                shoot = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (e.type = SDL_KEYUP  && e.key.repeat == 1)
    {
        switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_SPACE:
            {
                shoot = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (shoot)
    {
        Shot newShot(player.getDir(), player);
        shots.push_back(newShot);
    }

    return shots;
}
```

And this is how I move the player

```
void Player::handleEvent(SDL_Event& e)
{
    if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && e.key.repeat == 0)
    {
        switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_w: mVelY -= PLAYER_VEL; mDir = 0; break;
            case SDLK_s: mVelY += PLAYER_VEL; mDir = 1; break;
            case SDLK_d: mVelX += PLAYER_VEL; mDir = 2; break;
            case SDLK_a: mVelX -= PLAYER_VEL; mDir = 3; break;
        }
    }
    else if (e.type == SDL_KEYUP && e.key.repeat == 0)
    {
        switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_w: mVelY += PLAYER_VEL; break;
            case SDLK_s: mVelY -= PLAYER_VEL; break;
            case SDLK_d: mVelX -= PLAYER_VEL; break;
            case SDLK_a: mVelX += PLAYER_VEL; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate your event polling from the rest of the game logic.

Poll all events *once* per frame in a separate function and store the state of the keystates into an array. Then, when you need the state, simply check the array.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [SDL_GetKeyboardState](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) to sample the surrent state of the keys, without having to handle the key events yourself.

Comment: This answer only applies to SDL 2, right? The question seems to be about SDL 1.x

Comment: SDL1.2 have `SDL_GetKeyState` that does virtually the same thing.